# Persian words changed to ??? in Orchard

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I've build an orchard site on my local machine. this site is in three language and on my local computer every this is good.
But after I published my site on remote server; for example when I want to add a new page in **Persian language**, after saving word to database every words changed to ????.
site address is http://modernsaraylar.com/ and I don't know how to fix it.
by the way, I have put all of the tables collation to utf8-persian-ci but it doesn't work :(

TNX in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add "CharSet=utf8" at the end of connection string and it solved the problem. It you use MySQL you will have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL then you will have to change the column type should be changed to nvarchar instead of varchar

Comment: TNX, it was nvarchar. the problem was with connection string, because my database was MySql I had to add CharSet=utf8 at connection string.